# Collapse dataframe based on minimum integer value, but also filling null string values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

| ID | Check 1 | Check 2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Y | 1 |
| 1 | Y | Y | 2 |
| 2 |  | Y | 5 |
| 2 |  |  | 8 |

I have a dataframe similar to the above table. I need to find a way to collapse the table so that I have only one row for each ID, and the Value column contains the minimum value for that ID.

I'm able to do this using:

```
df = df.fillna('')
df.groupby(['ID'],as_index=False).min()
```

However I also need to preserve any of the 'Y' values in my two Check columns, so that a Y will always take priority and fill in any null values on a row with the same ID. So based on the table above, the result I'm looking for would be like this:

| ID | Check 1 | Check 2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | Y | 1 |
| 2 |  | Y | 5 |

What I'm seeing happen so far is that I'll be left with blanks in my Check 1 column, instead of a Y value. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `sort_values` on the "Value" column before `groupby`, you can simply keep the `first` valid row for all columns:

```
>>> df.sort_values("Value").groupby("ID").first().fillna('')
   Check 1 Check 2  Value
ID                       
1        Y       Y      1
2                Y      5
```

Answer (score 2):

Group the dataframe by `ID`, then pass `min` as aggregate for `Value` column, and `first` as aggregate for rest of the columns.

```py
>>> df.groupby('ID').agg({'Check 1': 'first', 'Check 2':'first', 'Value': 'min'})
 
   Check 1 Check 2  Value
ID                       
1        Y       Y      1
2     None       Y      5
```